# How to INNER JOIN with CASE and LIKE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to combine the following two SQL statements into one:

```
Select A.Parameter,
  A.Value,
  A.Indicator,
  B.Parameter,
  B.Value
From A
  Inner Join B On (A.Parameter Like '%' + B.Parameter + '%')
```

```
 Case 
    When A.Indicator = higher AND B.Value < A.Value Then 1
    When A.Indicator = equal AND B.Value != A.Value Then 1
    When A.Indicator = lower AND B.Value > A.Value Then 1
Else 0
End As EvalCheck
```

So I need to join them based on the parameter name with a `LIKE`, since they are slightly different. Also, I need to compare the values of the parameters at the same time based on the `Indicator` and set the column `EvalCheck` to 1 or 0.

Desired result:

```
Parameter   Value_A Indicator   Value_B EvalCheck
ParameterA  0   equal   1   1
ParameterB  3   higher  4   0
ParameterC  5   higher  4   1
ParameterD  3   higher  4   0
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Copy-paste the conditions from CASE to the ON clause.

Comment: Putting a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` or `ON` is generally a bad idea; it makes your query non-SARGable. Stick to Boolean Logic. Unfortunately, the fact that you have a leading wildcard in your `JOIN` already causes the query to be non-SARGable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just include the `case` expression in the `select`?

```
select A.Parameter, A.Value, A.Indicator,
       B.Parameter, B.Value,
       (case when A.Indicator = 'higher' and B.Value < A.Value then 1
             when A.Indicator = 'equal' and B.Value <> A.Value then 1
             when A.Indicator = 'lower' and B.Value > A.Value then 1
            else 0
       end) as EvalCheck
from A join
     B
     on A.Parameter Like '%' + B.Parameter + '%';
```